# Why do we use local phase symmetry if we can couple the EM field to a divergence free current without it?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance

[This](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/384978/) question is pretty much what I am confused about. However, the answer says that we require local phase symmetry to keep the lagrangian gauge invariant. As far as I can see the argument only works the other way around, i.e. we impose gauge transformation to make the local symmetry work. We can couple the EM field to a divergence free 4-vector.

Answer (score -1):

Local symmetry is not needed, at least in electromagnetism. We can get away with it because of charge conservation but I advise against it to avoid complications.

See my paper on this: https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0106078